# Use PHP to link to user profile

Tags: php, html

I want my php query to display the user name with a link to the user profile.

```
<?php

$get_items = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE category='test'";
$result = mysql_query($get_items);

while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $creator = $item['created_by'];
     echo "<b>Seller: </b>"."<a href='userprof.php?id=$creator'>$creator</a>";  
    }
?>
```

Clicking on this link takes it to a user profile page that I created. But I want "userprof.php?id=$creator" to know which user to display the account information. Is this the best way to do this? How can I read the url and display the correct information?

Comment: You should not use mysql_ functions in 2010.  Use PDO.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$userId = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = " . intval($userId);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
...
```

Comment: I think something is wrong with my while loop.   <?php
 $userId = $_GET['id'];
 echo "<div class=\"item_list\">";
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = " . intval($userId);
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
  while($userid = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

  echo "<b>Title: </b>" . $item['item'] . "<br/><b>Email: </b>". $item['email'] . "<br/>";
   echo "<b>Price: </b>" . $item['price'] . "</b><br/> <b>Category: </b>". $item['category'] . "</b><br/> <b>Extra: </b>". ($item['extra'] . "</b><br/><b>Date Listed: </b>". $item['date'] );
              
 }

Comment: You're not assigning anything to item. Try changing it to `while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a GET variable.

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // Contains whatever was in $creator;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$_GET` for getting the variable from the URL.
like in your code you want to access the user profile then get the user id from url
like

```
http://localhost/test/user_profile.php?uid=2
```

here in the url uid is 2 thet is your userid.
you can get this id by using the code

```
$user_id = $_GET['uid'];
```

use this variable in your query.

Answer (score 0):

OMG!!  HORRIBLE PHP ABOUNDS! IT HURTS MY EYES!!

These people, none of them did both of the correct things:

1. ALWAYS FILTER USER INPUT!!
2. NEVER TRUST PHP ESCAPE FUNCTIONS, ESP NOT `intval()` and `addslashes()`!!
3. EVEN `mysql_real_escape_string()` HAS VULNERABILITIES AND SHOULD NEVER BE USED.
4. You should used prepared statements for **everything** in 2010.

Here it is the proper way:

```
<?php
if (!filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
{
    trigger_error('Invalid User ID. It must be an integer (number).', PHP_USER_ERROR);
    exit;
}

$userId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?";

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;db=mydb', $dbUsername, $dbPassWord);
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array($userId));

$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

That is 100% secure.  I hope people neither vote me down nor tone down my answer.  Bad code is so systemic, we just have to shout from the rooftops until the new guys start learning it correctly, otherwise PHP as a professional language is seriously harmed.